# How to get and store multiple values from URL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a a requirement in PHP,

from a biometric machine a URL will pass like this:

website.com/rfid/attendance.php? - Web Host URL

```
$ - Start of data    
SID= XXXXX - Org ID (5 digits)     
& - Field Differentiator    
MID= XX - Machine ID (2 digits)    
&    
RFID= XXXXXXXXXX - Card ID (10 numeric digits User ID)     
&    
DOT=DDMMYYYYHHMMSS- Date of Transaction (14 digits)    
, - End of one record    
* - End of data
```

If one record to upload in one go:

```
http://website.com/rfid/attendance.php?$99999&99&0008478100&27122013113700*
```

If two records to upload in one go:

```
http://website.com/rfid/rfid_device.php?$99999&99&0008478100&27122013113700, 0008478200&27122013113700*
```

When 10 Records to upload in one go:

```
/rfid/rfid_device.php?0000000000000000$99999&99&0008478100&27122013113700,1234567100&27122013113700,1234567200&27122013113700,123456700&27122013113700,1234567200&27122013113700,1234567100&27122013113700,1234567100&27122013113700,1234567200&27122013113700,1234567100&27122013113700,1234567200&27122013113700*
```

How to get store values ? Please help.

Comment: There is a risk to HTTP 414 error: "Url too long". May be `POST` request will be better for this

Comment: nothing to doo..it's already configured in machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` super and then just use `explode()` to break apart the string...

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

**UPDATE:**

Untested code example: (it should be noted that I cannot remember if the super includes the '?' from the query string or not.)

```
$qs = str_replace('$', '', $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']); // get rid of the $
$qs = str_replace('*', '', $qs); // get rid of the *

$submissions = explode(',', $qs); // split the subs

$SID = ""; // store for sid
$MID = ""; // store for mid

// loop
for ($i = 0; $i < count($submissions); $i++) {
    $sections = explode('&', $submissions[$i]);

    if($i == 0) {
        $SID = $sections[0];
        $MID = $sections[1];
        $RFID = $sections[2];
        $DOT = $sections[3];
    } else {
        $RFID = $sections[0];
        $DOT = $sections[1];
    }

    // do things with the values
}
```

Comment: can u give an example of code brother..i coudn't understand

Comment: @swamy I have updated the post with some code.. it probably has syntax errors, but it should be enough to give you an idea of where to start..

Comment: @vp_arth Good spot! damn cut'n'paste coding haha

Comment: thanks @har0ld. It's fine working. But $ and * are coming with first and last values..

Comment: @swamy There is an error in my code on line 4. The second arg should be `$qs`. I will update my code for future reference.

Comment: @swamy nope. That is supposed to be `$i`.

Comment: ya thanks brother..I am not big developer so just got confusion. Thanks you very much for your help.

Comment: Date and time showing ALL 0 Values with timestamp filed type.

Answer (score -1):

PHP also recommends use of the Filter API over directly accessing $_* variables.

```
$querystr = filter_input( INPUT_SERVER, 'QUERY_STRING' );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php

Comment: isn't this unusable without third argument?

Comment: The 3rd and 4th arguments have defaults and can be omitted in the call.

Comment: And when omitted - `filter_input` does nothing :)

Comment: That's right. I didn't want to make assumptions on the needs of OP. That said, there are some decent built-in sanitizers available.

http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php